# Multiple port pika connection

Tags: python, amqp, pika

I'm trying to use pika to listen the queues of rabbitMQ, but I'm stuck trying to perform a multiple port connection. The connection adapters allow the port parameter only as an integer.

Is it possible to perform a multiple port connection using only one instance of an adapter (like in php-amqplib) or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: You will need one connection per port.

Comment: It looks so. It's disappointing because we use multiple ports for balancing the message load and in php it's so easy